# How to get mat-toolbar to respond to changes in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have been trying to make a basic header for the homepage, for my webapp for some time now, I want to use mat-toolbar, but it will not set the way that I want it to. My code is as follows.

```css
.maintooly {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7)
}
```

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="main-tooly">
    <span id="product-name">
        HOMEPAGE
    </span>
    <div class="vertical-line title-line">
        |
    </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This is a watered down example but essentially I am trying to add a header to the to top of the page so it would look like this:

[image: What I want]

But instead it is looking like this:

[image: What I'm getting]

Summmary: cannot get items in header to display side by side and cannot get the color of header to change or really do anything.

What exactly am I doing wrong here and how can I make this work?

Comment: Protip: Don't add markup to create lines. Use CSS.

Comment: Have you imported the toolbar module? Doesn't seem like it's loaded.

Comment: @isherwood How and where do I do that? How can I verify?

Comment: @isherwood In angular-material.module.ts I have import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

Comment: Well, your build should fail and/or you should have console errors if it's not loading.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put import the tool into app.module.ts file.